# is it possible to crawl one page to render it to another page in javascript and html?

Tags: javascript, html

At my company, we are debating this.  Say you have a color swatches that is already built in product detail page. At the category page, where each products are displayed, doesn't have color swatches.  So we are trying to build one.  I was suggesting if we can use jquery or javascript to crawl it, cache it or drag it from the pdp and display it in category page. If we do that, it probably gonna be very slow because the category page is going to hit the server many times.

Additional info, we don't have access to the php codes, so only javascript, jquery and html is possible.

I am actually looking for a way to do that. of course, it has to run fast too. Any suggestions of possibility anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think it is possible, your jquery or javascript should be native to the page to read its contents, ok lets assume it is native and you can read the content but where do you store ? with only javascript and jquery and not much of server side it is **impossible**